# Group sequential repeated values in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this Array:

```
var arr = ['a','a','b','b','b','c','d','d','a','a','a'];
```

I wish this output:

```
[
  ['a','a'],
  ['b','b','b'],
  ['c'],
  ['d','d'],
  ['a','a','a'],
]
```

Obs.: Notice that I dont want group all the repeat values. Only the sequential repeated values.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! As I'm sure you've read the article about how to ask a good question, you might know that this is not a coding service. Please show what you've tried so far and were you got stuck and we're happy to help!

Comment: It is a for loop, if check and pushing to  arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce your array like this:

```
var arr = ['a','a','b','b','b','c','d','d','a','a','a'];

var result = arr.reduce(function(r, i) {
    if (typeof r.last === 'undefined' || r.last !== i) {
        r.last = i;
        r.arr.push([]);
    }
    r.arr[r.arr.length - 1].push(i);
    return r;
}, {arr: []}).arr;

console.log(result);
```

see [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Answer (score 2):

Solution with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and a view to the former element.

```js
var arr = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
    result = [];

arr.reduce(function (r, a) {
    if (a !== r) {
        result.push([]);
    }
    result[result.length - 1].push(a);
    return a;
}, undefined);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```